# Question abut a Redshift error relating to Join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I run something almost identical to this successfully, but this code fails, and I cant seem to find the reason. I get the following message in SQLWorkbench:

**Message**

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT distinct ac.fund_id ,  flatMainAssetClass,flatManagerId
from tableau_prep.complete_fund_info

JOIN

(SELECT distinct fund_id, LISTAGG(main_a...

ERROR: syntax error at end of input
Position: 688

**Code:**

```sql
  (SELECT distinct fund_id, LISTAGG(main_asset_class,',')
  WITHIN GROUP (Order by main_asset_class)
  OVER (PARTITION BY fund_id) AS flatMainAssetClass
  FROM
      (SELECT distinct fund_id,main_asset_class from tableau_prep.complete_fund_info ) 
      )
      
  AS ac
  
JOIN 
    (SELECT distinct fund_id ,LISTAGG(manager_id,',')
     WITHIN GROUP (Order by manager_id)
     OVER (PARTITION BY fund_id) AS flatManagerId
     FROM
          (SELECT distinct fund_id,manager_id from tableau_prep.complete_fund_info)
          )
          AS mgr
     on ac.fund_id = mgr.fund_id
```

Comment: What is that *almost identical* something? afaics you are missing an outer `select`

Comment: `(select ..) from (..)` is invalid SQL to begin with. But Postgres also has no `listagg()` function and it doesn't support `within group` either.

Comment: I used Postgres but specifically meant Redshift. Thanks for the answers